# Architecture for specific paths to request different servers

Tags: node.js, api, express, nginx, architecture

I'm building a short link application like bit.ly using the MERN stack. I want the static pages of the app to be hosted on a seperate server from the API. My architecture needs to be:

#### API:

**POST** - `example.com/link` - create short link.
**PUT** - `example.com/link:slug` - update short link.
**GET** - `example.com/:slug` - fetch/redirect short link to long link.

### Static site:

**GET** - `example.com` - Homepage.
**GET** - `example.com/:slug-that-doesnt-exist` - 404 page.
**GET** - `example.com/blog, example.com/docs, example.com/support etc.` - Various static pages

The issue I'm having is getting the server to delineate between the two types of requests to the same domain, often on the same path.

`example.com/abc123` is the API while `example.com/blog` is the static site, even though the express router `example.com/:slug` is matching both. To complicate it `example.com/zxy987` hits the API but doesn't exist so needs to redirect the request to the static server. I also can't figure out how to redirect the request itself without the URL changing to the other server. I considered using NGINX but it doesn't appear it could handle the `example.com/:slug-that-doesnt-exist` type requests since it wouldn't know if they exist at the time it runs.

What is the 'best' way to approach this?

Comment: Is there a reason they need to be hosted on a separate server? It seems like you could just define everything on one instance, then define all of your static routes prior to your slug.

Comment: @JasonRoman The main reason is so that I can modify my homepage, push new blog posts/docs, etc. without having to push a new build to my API server which could possibly cause downtime. Also it would allow me to scale the servers independently since with a short link application its likely to get farm more API redirect calls than it is to get say a blog post.

Comment: If that is the case why not just define your API as `api.example.com` and have a separate nginx config? You can then do everything I said above on your main site, and then forward any actual slug requests to your API server to get the redirect response, and redirect the user.